# What is multi-head attention doing mathematically, and how is it different from self-attention?

Tags: deep-learning, comparison, transformer, attention

I'm trying to understand the difference between the concept of *self-attention* and *multi-head attention*. The latter is not actually too clear to me.

I understand that, in the case of self-attention, we start with a feature matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, and then we use the same linear transformation $W$ to produce

\begin{align}
Q &= XW \\ 
K &= XW \\
V &= XW
\end{align}

and then we compute the following

$$X' = \text{softmax} \left(\frac{Q\cdot K^T}{\sqrt{d}} \right)V$$

where $X' \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ is a new version of the input matrix, where the pairwise interactions between the points will be encoded.

What is multi-head attention doing, from a mathematical point of view, and what's the difference? I know we are going to use three *different* linear transformations in this case (so no weight-sharing), but what exactly will be encoded using three different $W$? Maybe it's more the conceptual view that it's not too clear in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I believe that in self-attention mechanism for Query, Key and Value vectors the different linear transformations are used,
$$
Q = XW_Q,\,K = XW_K,\,V = XW_V; W_Q \neq W_K, W_K \neq W_V, W_Q \neq W_V
$$
The self-attention itself is a way of using more general attention mechanism. You can check [this post](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2018-06-24-attention/) for examples of other mechanisms that can be used.

Multi-head attention is a way of grouping together a bunch of attention mechanism ( Usually they are all the same type ), which consists in just running multiple mechanism in parallel and aggregating the resulting set in some way. In [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) for example, the aggregation is done by concatenation and weighted sum of the outputs, e.g.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{MultiHead}(Q, K, V)= [\text{head}_1, .., \text{head}_n]W^O & [..] \text{ meaning concatenation}\\
&\text{where head}_i = \text{Attention}(QW_i^Q,KW_i^K,VW_i^V) & \text{each head}_i\text{ is unique attention mechanism} \\
&\text{Attention}(\textbf{Q},\textbf{K},\textbf{V}) = \text{softmax}(\frac{\textbf{Q}\textbf{K}}{\sqrt{d_k}})\textbf{V} & \text{this can be other attention mechanism}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: are you sure that they are different? In the following document people.tamu.edu/~sji/classes/attn-slides.pdf (slide 5) it is clearly stated that *in self-attention, we let Q=K=V=X *

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i checked it out.
I think what happens is a misunderstanding in what Q, K, V are. In the slides you have provided they are seen as already transformed X that is passed to attention mechanism and transformed once again, kind of in the same way as I have established i-th head in the multi-head attention.

Comment: But since they are transformed again after being passed to the self attention, it is actually equivalent to what I have described as self attention. The only difference is that its applied to pre-transformed X.

Imagine, that we are pre-transforming X to X*W. Now by applying the self attention I have described you are going to obtain the exact same result as in the slide 3 you have mentioned.
I adopted this point of view, since this is the way its described in Attention is All you need paper.
Check this for an example https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-self-attention-2d627e33b20a